# Get access token for Xero with API calls

Tags: xero-api, xero

I created account without verification via auth app on a phone, because with that I wont be able to automate it.
So first I followed this instruction [here](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/guides/oauth2/auth-flow/#2-users-are-redirected-back-to-you-with-a-code)

What I did is:

Step 1: Generated link just like described in step 1, so when I do all I should in return get `code` and `state` (parsing it from url), so in response let say I got

```
state=123456
code=vcciFJW_bFTjodGQnNUk7BIr-EoSBQSktn-cNUGdDjY
```

Step 2: With using restassured, I call  `POST https://identity.xero.com/connect/token` URI to get access token. So my request look like:

```
Request method: POST
Request URI:    https://identity.xero.com/connect/token
Proxy:          <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params:   <none>
Form params:    <none>
Path params:    <none>
Headers:        Authorization=Basic <here my generated base54 encoded data>
                Accept=*/*
                Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1
Cookies:        <none>
Multiparts:     <none>
Body:
{
  "grant_type" : "authorization_code",
  "redirect_uri" : "https://developer.xero.com/",
  "code" : "vcciFJW_bFTjodGQnNUk7BIr-EoSBQSktn-cNUGdDjY"
}
```

Which return to me

```
400
{"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}
```

Any particular reason for that ?
Why would I need to do that is basically we have postman collection to fill data for testing, but we'd like to create a job for that instead without having collections in postman and running it manually.

UPDATED (after some changes due to error with request I made):

```
    Request method: POST
    Request URI:    https://identity.xero.com/connect/token
    Proxy:          <none>
    Request params: <none>
    Query params:   <none>
    Form params:    grant_type=authorization_code
                    code=3_Lli3YQYPyFlf_RoZJGRVE5iPGCeo-H9ta9htdr8ec
                    redirect_uri=https://developer.xero.com/
    Path params:    <none>
    Headers:        Authorization=Basic <base64 encoded string>
                    Accept=*/*
                    Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1
    Cookies:        <none>
    Multiparts:     <none>
    Body:           <none>
    400
    {"error":"unauthorized_client"}
```

Problem solved, issue was with redirect_uri, I used uri without / at the end when logging and use uri with / when call token endpoint. In Troubleshooting page written that URLs must be equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, issue was with redirect_uri, I used uri without / at the end when logging and use uri with / when call token endpoint. In Troubleshooting page written that URLs must be equal

Comment: could you provide an example for your solution?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are base64 encoding and that the base54 is a typo?

Please can you check how you are generating the body of the request and how it is formatted. Searching for that code I can see that the error in the Xero logs is "Grant type is missing" which suggests that it may be there but can't be read as it is ill-formed.

Comment: It turned our that the request I made is not correct as long as this is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, so I made changes and now instead body I sent formParams, but now API returns me `400` with `unauthorized_client` error. I'm using java.util.Base64 class to encode my clientId and secret

Comment: If you haven't resolved this yet, please can you raise a case with Xero Support using this form https://developer.xero.com/contact-xero-developer-platform-support. Please can you provide details of your client id and, the date and time (and timezone) for a recent error 400